# python classes within a class but take method from class above.

Tags: python

My code looks like the lines underneath. But I have duplicate code, because the `print_function` does appear 2 times.

```
   class A():
     class B():
       def print_function():
         print('yippie')

       def main():
         print_function()

     class C():
       def print_function():
         print('yippie')

       def main():
         print_function()
```

But how to I change the code, so that it looks like this:

```
   class A():
      def print_function():
            print('yippie')

      class B():
         def main():
           print_function()

      class C():
        def main():
          print_function()
```

Comment: Why do you have nested classes? And have you learned about inheritance yet?

Comment: You should be using inheritance. This isn't the right model to be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, if you want the behaviour you are looking for, you must specify an *inheritence hierarchy*. In your case, `A` forms the *parent*/*superclass*, while B, C form the *children*/*subclasses*.

This is how you'd define them.

```
In [678]: class A():
     ...:     def print_function(self):
     ...:         print('yippie')
     ...: 
     ...: class B(A):
     ...:     def main(self):
     ...:         self.print_function()
     ...: 
     ...: class C(A):
     ...:     def main(self):
     ...:       self.print_function()
     ...:
```

The syntax `class X(Y)` specifies `X` to be a `subclass` of `Y` and automatically inherits its attributes and methods, allowing you to call superclass methods through subclass objects.

Instantiating an object of `C`, you have:

```
In [679]: foo = C()

In [680]: foo.main()
yippie
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be accomplished by [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).

As a *very* bare bones example:

```
class A:

    def print_function(self):

        print("Yippie!")

class B(A):

    pass

class C(A):

    pass
```

Where a call to the `print_function()` of an instance of either class `B` or `C` will call the `print_function()` inherited from class `A`. We can run a simple test to verify the results like so:

```
>>> my_B = B()
>>> my_B.print_function()
Yippie!
```